# Bully for WPS wireless auditing: is it possible to continue an interrupted --bruteforce PIN test?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, wps

[Bully](https://github.com/bdpurcell/bully) is a neat program for wireless auditing: it allows to **test WPS PINs** against my router or access point so I can know if it is secure enough.
Example:

```
$ sudo bully mon0 --bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 -v 3 --bruteforce --pin 63370000
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'mon0' to channel '6'
[!] Using 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '11:22:33:44:55:66' on channel '6'
[+] Got beacon for 'NoamChomsky' (11:22:33:44:55:66)
[+] Loading randomized pins from '/root/.bully/pins'
[+] Index of starting pin number is '6337228'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '85389380'
[+] Rx(  M5  ) = 'Pin1Bad'   Next pin '75329389'
[+] Rx(  M5  ) = 'Pin1Bad'   Next pin '99129385'
...
^C
Saved session to '/root/.bully/112233445566.run'
```

as you see (note the reference to "randomized pins"), PINs are checked calculating them according to the **WPS specification** (so they seem not have a logical ordering).
If I want to **continue** the test, there is no problem at all: the same command line automatically yields:

```
$ sudo bully mon0 --bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 -v 3
[!] Restoring session from '/root/.bully/112233445566.run'
...
^C
```

But sometimes the interesting part is to not keeping the WPS specification for 8-digit PINs (something about checksums and so on), but **test them all** (also known as bruteforce mode).
Example (note the reference to "sequential mode") starting from PIN `63370000`:

```
$ sudo bully mon0 --bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 -v 3 --bruteforce --pin 63370000
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'mon0' to channel '6'
[!] Starting pin specified, defaulting to sequential mode
[!] Using 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '11:22:33:44:55:66' on channel '6'
[+] Got beacon for 'NoamChomsky' (11:22:33:44:55:66)
[+] Index of starting pin number is '63370000'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '63370000'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370001'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370002'
^C
Saved session to '/root/.bully/8c0ca32a2751.run'
```

And here comes the problem, because if the test is aborted (or disconnected, or computer hangs... etc) and I desire to **continue** it later:

```
$ sudo bully mon0 --bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 -v 3 --bruteforce --pin 63370000
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'mon0' to channel '6'
[!] Starting pin specified, defaulting to sequential mode
[!] Using 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '11:22:33:44:55:66' on channel '6'
[+] Got beacon for 'NoamChomsky' (11:22:33:44:55:66)
[!] Restoring session from '/root/.bully/8c0ca32a2751.run'
[+] Index of starting pin number is '63370000'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '63370000'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370001'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370002'
```

It seems (note the sequence restarting from `63370000`) the `Restoring session from` is **not behaving as it should**.

The odd part is that testing the full spectrum of numbers can easily last hours or even days, so restoring the task is an important matter here.
What can I do to continue WPS PINs testing from the point where the program stopped last time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Locate the last PIN** tested from the storage progress file (the first number in the last line until the ":"):

```
$ tail /root/.bully/112233445566.run
# session ended 2014-04-27 03:08:48 with signal 2
63370002:63370002:1::
```

You can extract it directly by using `cut`:

```
$ tail /root/.bully/112233445566.run -n 1 | cut -d ":" -f 1
63370002
```

And **continue** from there:

```
$ sudo bully mon0 --bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 -v 3 --bruteforce --pin 63370002
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'mon0' to channel '6'
[!] Starting pin specified, defaulting to sequential mode
[!] Using 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '11:22:33:44:55:66' on channel '6'
[+] Got beacon for 'NoamChomsky' (11:22:33:44:55:66)
[!] Restoring session from '/root/.bully/8c0ca32a2751.run'
[+] Index of starting pin number is '63370002'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '63370002'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370003'
[+] Rx(  M7  ) = 'Pin2Bad'   Next pin '63370004'
```

I don't think that the "Restoring session" message makes any sense here, but anyway you can solve the problem.